Firestore security throws PERMISSION_DENIED when using nextjs server side component and firebase auth
I'm attempting to use nextjs 14 server side rendering with a firestore security rule that matches the auth state. I use firebase authentication for my auth.
Here's the firestore security rule that's failing:
 allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == 'sNyxMTrZohW4mPxkCiEEoc80JfO2';

Trying to run a query (in this case getCountFromServer()) results in the below error:
Uncaught Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I tested the rule in the Rules Playground and it succeeds when the uid matches, and I verified I am authenticated and the uid is correct by logging the entire auth object to the console.
Below is my nextjs code, including what I'm logging to console:
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

const AdminPage: React.FC = async () => {
    const fetchCount = async () => {
        const db = getFirestore()
        const coll = collection(db, "test_results");
        const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(coll);
        const count = snapshot.data().count
        const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
        console.log("CURRENT USER : ", currentUser)
        return count;
    }

    const count = await fetchCount()

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <p>COUNT : {count}</p>
            </div>
        </>

    )
};

The force-dynamic I don't think is doing anything as the page was already dynamic, but I wanted to make absolutely sure I wasn't having some weird caching issue. If I replace the security rule with if true; everything works fine. I have a hunch that this is related to this already described behavior in another SO post, but I am using firebase for auth and when I console log the current user it returns the correct firebase auth object, so my understanding is my firestore request should automatically include the auth information.
My function to get the current user returns this value:
return cookies().get("session")?.value;

And the cookie was previously set via firebase auth like this:
const auth = getAuth(firebaseAdminApp);
auth.createSessionCookie(idToken, sessionCookieOptions);

EDIT --
The firebase auth user (below) is undefined, so it appears from firebase's perspective I'm not logged in. I created my cookie with auth.createSessionCookie() though, ie. via firebase. Am I not actually logged in until I call verifySessionCookie()? I don't understand.
    const auth = getAuth();
    console.log(auth.currentUser?.uid) // undefined


If you think the problem is the same as in the question you linked, you can verify that by logging the auth state (console.log(auth.currentUser.uid)) right before you call getCountFromServer. Your code now logs it after that call.

Hi puf, I see your answers a lot, I really appreciate the help :) So per your suggestion I logged the .uid on what I thought was my auth object and the uid was correct. But then I looked at the firebase getAuth() and auth.currentUser?.uid, and it shows undefined. So now I'm confused, because my cookie was written via firebase createSessionCookie(), but this doesn't actually log me in? Do I now need to pass my session id to firebase somehow? I am struggling to find other answers about this online.

I checked out this other SO post. It's from 2019, but is it still true that if I use session cookies, I have to write my own custom security now for firestore? There's no other way to authenticate with nextjs server components afaik, so this is so frustrating. My use case is different than in the other post, because I am authenticated server side with a normal user, but I think I'm hitting the same issue described. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383814/detect-authenticated-users-in-firestore-security-rules-while-using-firebase-sess?rq=2

I made a new post for this specific issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78951226/how-to-set-auth-currentuser-when-using-session-cookies
