How to set auth.currentUser when using session cookies?
I'm using nextjs 14 app router. My entire backend is firebase, which includes app hosting, auth, and firestore.
In nextjs, afaik, I need to use session cookies for auth if I use server side rendering (SSR). I'm creating the session cookie with auth.createSessionCookie() which is part of the firebase sdk.
Using auth.creationSessionCookie() doesn't keep me logged in client side though, ie. auth.currentUser === null. This is a problem because any firestore security rules which check for auth no longer work since request.auth is also always null.
I want some sort of function like signInWithSessionCookie(), a way to pass my session cookie to firestore in my request, or some workaround. But after research, like this other SO question and the firebase documentation, I can't find a way to do this. It's really surprising though, because this auth pattern is essentially how every single nextjs app would function, and firebase is a huge service trying to support nextjs. Am I missing something here?

When you use cookies for authentication, you cannot use the Firebase client SDK to manage user's auth state and must be entirely managed using cookies.
It is similar to the traditional way of creating your own cookie based authentication except Firebase takes care of the tokens/cookies and revoking them as necessary.
You will have to implement an API that takes user's Firebase ID Token once user logs in with client SDK and then sets the session cookie.
import "server-only";

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { authAdmin } from "@/utils/firebase-admin";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

// /api/auth/login
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const authorization = request.headers.get("authorization")?.split(" ")[1];

  const sessionCookie = await authAdmin.createSessionCookie(authorization, {
    expiresIn: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 14 days in ms (maximum)
  });

  // setting the session cookie
  cookies().set("session", sessionCookie, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    domain: "localhost",
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Logged in" });
}

You should ideally set the Firebase auth persistence to NONE so user is logged out of Firebase client SDK later. You can then call the previously implemented API as follows:
// Sample login page
"use client";

import { auth } from "../../utils/firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getIdToken } from "firebase/auth";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const signUpUser = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );

      // call POST /api/auth/login with user's token
      const token = await getIdToken(userCredential.user);

      const response = await fetch("/api/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
     
      // redirect user
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className="max-w-sm mx-auto" onSubmit={signUpUser}>
      <div className="mb-5">
        <label>Your email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
          value={email}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-5">
        <label>Your password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
          value={password}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  );
}

Once your user is logged in, you will have to check for their auth states using cookies. You can do so using Next Middlewares like this:
// middleware.ts

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { authAdmin } from "./utils/firebase-admin";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  if (pathname.startsWith("/_next") || pathname.startsWith("/favicon.ico")) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const authorization = request.headers.get("authorization")?.split(" ")[1];

  if (!authorization) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
  }

  try {
    const { uid } = await authAdmin.verifyIdToken(authorization);
    console.log("Current user:", uid)

    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed to decode session cookie")
    // Unauthorized user..
  }
}

I would recommend creating another API to fetch user's detail that you can use to render current user's information in places like navigation bar.
To summarize, you must check user's auth state on server side ideally within middleware to then conditionally redirect users to login/dashboard pages.

Thanks for the reply Dharmaraj. I'd like to clarify my question though. Everything mentioned is what I'm already doing. I'm not trying to implement auth with nextjs and firebase, as I have already done this and it's working. My specific issue is that I want to be able to use the auth.currentUser object in firestore security rules. I don't want to rely on middleware for data protection, as 1. a security principle is protect data as close to the source as possible (ie. firestore security), 2. I don't want to implement my own security, 3. middleware has limitations in firebase app hosting

@esafresa you cannot use auth.currentUser if you are using cookies. Again, it's the traditional cookie base authentication and Firebase is just generating/managing the cookie so you won't have to. Since you wish to use server-side rendering in your application, the data must be fetched using Firebase Admin SDK on the server side so you are responsible for checking users' access to their data. You technically can persist client side auth as well for any operations happening between client and Firebase directly but I would not recommend using both Firebase SDK and Cookies.

I see, okay. That's kinda what I thought. I submitted a feature request to firebase for this. Unless there's some underlying reason this isn't possible? I don't know a lot about auth, so maybe I'm wrong. This whole architecture is pretty confusing but from my understanding, I don't think firebase app hosting has edge processing (yes it has edge, but is there compute on the edge?), which means using nextjs middleware isn't optimal, and if the alternative for checking auth is route handlers... seems like nextjs/firebase just aren't good together. Probably i switch to Vercel, which is a pain.
